# How does "$" work in "apt-cache search something$"

Tags: apt, regular-expression

I understand that:

```
$ apt-cache search package_name
```

will search for matches in names and descriptions.

But how does this work?

```
$ apt-cache search package_name$
```

For example,

```
$ apt-cache search desktop
```

will produce a list of names and short descriptions of packages that have "desktop" anywhere in the name or description.

Then, if I understand correctly,

```
$ apt-cache search desktop$
```

should produce a subset in which "desktop" is the last word either in the name or in **any line** in the description.

But I found one example, `xjig`, which shows up with `apt-cache search desktop` but doesn't show up with `apt-cache search desktop$` even though the description according to `apt-cache show xjig` has "desktop" in the second-last line of the description:

> Description-en: An X11 jigsaw puzzle
>    xjig is a puzzle that tries to replicate a jigsaw puzzle on the screen
>    as closely as possible. Any GIF, JPEG or PPM image may be loaded and cut
>    into pieces. The goal (as with any jigsaw puzzle) is to reassemble the
>    original picture.
>    .
>    Tiles may be freely rotated by use of the mouse, flipped (for
>    double-sided puzzles) and even shown as shaped windows on the **desktop**
>    (fast machine/video card recommended for the latter!). An example image
>    is provided in /usr/share/games/xjig .

So why is `xjig` not included in the output of `apt-cache search desktop$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `apt-cache` man page:

```
search regex...
   search performs a full text search on all available package lists for the 
   POSIX regex pattern given, see regex(7). It searches the package names 
   and the descriptions for an occurrence of the regular expression and 
   prints out the package name and the short description, including virtual 
   package names. If --full is given then output identical to show is 
   produced for each matched package, and if --names-only is given then the 
   long description is not searched, only the package name is.

   Separate arguments can be used to specify multiple search patterns that 
   are and'ed together.
```

Notice it states `regex(7)`. So when you tell `apt-cache` to search for something you're providing it a regular expression. The `$` in a regex means that you want to match, anchored to the end of strings.

So if we're gave the value `desktop$` we'd only match strings where `desktop` was at the end of strings such as:

- this is a desktop
- this is a very long  string with desktop

But it wouldn't match strings such as:

- this is desktop in the window
- this is another desktop in the window

In your case the string `desktop` in xjig's description, though at the end of a line in the description, is not at the end of the description field's value.

#### Example

Here's xjig's description.

```
Description-en: An X11 jigsaw puzzle
 xjig is a puzzle that tries to replicate a jigsaw puzzle on the screen
 as closely as possible. Any GIF, JPEG or PPM image may be loaded and cut
 into pieces. The goal (as with any jigsaw puzzle) is to reassemble the
 original picture.
 .
 Tiles may be freely rotated by use of the mouse, flipped (for
 double-sided puzzles) and even shown as shaped windows on the desktop
 (fast machine/video card recommended for the latter!). An example image
 is provided in /usr/share/games/xjig .
```

If I search for all strings that end with `xjig .$`.

```
$ apt-cache search 'xjig \.$'
xjig - An X11 jigsaw puzzle
```

Remember that the value for the description is just a long string that is wrapped at that point, so though "desktop" is at the end a line, it isn't actually at the end of the description's value.

#### Alternative

Given you're looking for the word `desktop` you could look for the string with either spaces on either side (`\s`), or word boundaries (`\b`).

```
$ apt-cache search '\sdesktop\s' | grep xjig
xjig - An X11 jigsaw puzzle

$ apt-cache search '\bdesktop\b' | grep xjig
xjig - An X11 jigsaw puzzle
```

#### Understanding regex anchors

Perhaps using `grep` to see what an anchor does in a regex would help.

*desktop not at the end*

```
$ echo "this is a desktop string" | grep "desktop$"
$
```

*desktop at the end*

```
$ echo "this is a desktop" | grep "desktop$"
this is a desktop
```

The compliment to `$` for anchoring matches to the end of strings, is the `^` for anchoring matches to the beginning.

*desktop not at beginning*

```
$ echo "this is a desktop" | grep "^desktop"
$
```

*desktop at beginning*

```
$ echo "desktop this is a desktop" | grep "^desktop"
desktop this is a desktop
```

Comment: I am able to understand "In your case the string desktop in xjig's description, though at the end of a line in the description, is not at the end of the description field's value." I think that would explain my confusion. But why did you give `apt-cache search xjig .$` as an example? That has me confused again. Doesn't it mean we're now searching for two terms, xjig and .$?

Comment: @vasa1 - no we're looking for a string "xjig ." but only ones that are at the end of the strings we're attempting to match. Remember we're quoting the arguments to `apt-cache search` in single quotes, so it's a single argument we're looking for.

Comment: Okay, but why the space after `xjig`and before the period?

Comment: @vasa1 - that's how the description shows up for xjig. No other reason than that. Run this `apt-cache show xjig` and look at how the Description field shows up.

Answer (score 3):

The *description* field is a multi-line field but `$` in the regexp, means the end of the field, not the end of each line of the field. So, if you want to search for `desktop` at the end of a line or at the end of the field, you need:

```
apt-cache search 'desktop(
|$)'
```

Or with the ksh93 `$'...'` quotes (also found in `zsh` and `bash`) allowing `\x` escape sequences:

```
apt-cache search $'desktop(\n|$)'
```

Also note that `.` does match a newline character. Written in `perl`, that would be:

```
print "$name - $summary" if 
   $name =~ qr{$re}si ||
   $description =~ qr{$re}si;
```

(except they are not perl regexps of course)

Comment: You might want to explain the `$''` notation. Most ppl are not familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, I was about to ask that because `apt-cache search 'desktop(\n|$)'` apparently works as well.

Comment: @vasa1. Hmmm. Weird, `'desktop(\n|$)'` seems to work indeed, but not `'desktop\n'` nor `'desktop(\n)'`. I don't know why.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - yeah I noticed the 'desktop\n' didn't work either. I left it out of my answer as to not confuse the situation further. That's why I went with the `\b` approach.